# How to back to MainActivity after StartActivity other app in Android?

Tags: android

I want to back to MainActivity in RecognitionListener

```
onResults(Bundle results) { 
if(results == "go to keep"){
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.google.android.keep", "com.google.android.keep.activities.BrowseActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
}
if(results == "back")
//back to MainActivity
}
```

Comment: how did you get to that activity? use that approach to go back sir, or `super.onBackpressed();`

Comment: I want to say back to restart MainActivity ,not press back button to back to restart MainActivity

Comment: sir can you repeat what you said i can not understand, you can write it in your native language i will translate to english

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can set it up in the Manifest to have a parent.

Look here: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html

If you're trying to start MainActivity from Recognition listener then you want to do something like this: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: I try it ,it need two activity but I have only one Activity, the Activity implements RecognitionListener to open like keep app or youtube app ,i want to say "back" to restart the Activity , app opened will disappear or be killed